# How to change an internal screenlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my activity I have a link. When i clicked on this link, i will make a FrameLayout visbile, which contains a VideoView and the corresponding video will be played.

I am able to play this video and is in portrait screen layout.

But i want the internal FrameLayout or Video Player displayed in Landscape screen orientation.

How can i do this?

I know that **setRequestedOrientation(           ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);** will rotate the screen to Landscape but all my views in the activity are distorted.

I dont want to change the entire activity layout, rather i just want my internal FrameLayout to be changed. How can i do this?

From the below screenshot, i want just the player to be displayed in Landscape mode, thats it.

[image]

Comment: if you want your activty to resume the layout as it is in landscape mode add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in the activity of manifest file for which activity you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is to Switch between two layouts according to the orientation,one layout optimized for Potrait and one for Landscape,and you should do this `onCreate` method,while setting Content View,this way it will check what the orientation is and automatically `setContentView` according to the orientation

Answer (score 0):

you need to create two Xmls for the landscape and portrait using this you are easily able to achieve your result. Save the fields data if you want that data after orientation change. in `onSaveInstanceState` and retrieve it from `onRestoreInstanceState`.